# Why logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler log file create time is "drifting" causing headache for ETL

Tags: python, logging, web-applications, handlers

I'm having an issue with python's logging module's **TimeRotatingFileHandler** where each consecutive log file's create time appears to be "drifting" away from the desired top of the hour rotation. See example:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 1278 Oct 13 18:58 activity.log.2014-10-13_18
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 1260 Oct 13 19:58 activity.log.2014-10-13_19
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 1512 Oct 13 21:00 activity.log.2014-10-13_20
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 1266 Oct 13 22:05 activity.log.2014-10-13_21
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 2128 Oct 13 23:10 activity.log.2014-10-13_22
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3234 Oct 14 00:10 activity.log.2014-10-13_23
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3739 Oct 14 01:10 activity.log.2014-10-14_00
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3388 Oct 14 02:11 activity.log.2014-10-14_01
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3122 Oct 14 03:11 activity.log.2014-10-14_02
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3108 Oct 14 04:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_03
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3066 Oct 14 05:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_04
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3178 Oct 14 06:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_05
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3126 Oct 14 07:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_06
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3532 Oct 14 08:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_07
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 2954 Oct 14 09:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_08
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3463 Oct 14 10:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_09
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3743 Oct 14 11:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_10
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3867 Oct 14 12:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_11
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 3687 Oct 14 13:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_12
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 4141 Oct 14 14:12 activity.log.2014-10-14_13
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 4172 Oct 14 15:13 activity.log.2014-10-14_14
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 4186 Oct 14 16:13 activity.log.2014-10-14_15
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 4578 Oct 14 17:13 activity.log.2014-10-14_16
```

The log here is capturing sporadic events that occur on my web app. I implemented a cron job to ping the webapp (to trigger a roll) every minute on 10/14 at 11pm, so you'll notice that the "drift" is improved but still occurs gradually over the course of the day. This is causing a major headache for my database ETL jobs that are cron'd to run at specific hours.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this so that it rolls over at a single minute every hour of every day? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Created a work-around by modifying a cron'd python script to ping my webapp every second for a minute +/- the last log creation minute. This appears to be triggering the log to roll over consistently at the same time in the subsequent hours and avoid the "drift".